# Can Linux multipathing be used to manage non-SCSI block devices

Tags: linux

I am familiar with Linux Multpath and how it detects the SCSI devices (/dev/sd*) and maps them to a single device.  Can I instruct "multipath/device mapper" to map/manage a block device that is not a SCSI device.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Can you tell us what sort of block device you're asking about?

Comment: It's a block device (as opposed to a character device) that is exported by a driver that I wrote.  I am trying to find out if I can somehow get DM-Multipath to detect this block device.

Comment: I am trying to find out how does DM-Multipath detect the devices that it can control.  Does "it" look for devices in a certain directory or with special name (sd*) or one that responds to a specific command?  It seems DM-Multipath uses WWID to uniquely identify a device, and use that ID to group devices that are the same, and create a single entry for it to be used by applications.  What is the exact definition of WWID?  How does DM-Multipath retrieve the WWID from a device?

Comment: Based on the documentation from the dm-multipath home page, it seems multipath only manages SCSI block devices, as it uses some SCSI commands to get from the device to recognize the device.  http://christophe.varoqui.free.fr/refbook.html